# Getting a "Compile Error: Expected: End of Statement" when trying to return a calculated value from a function

Tags: excel, vba

I have coded a function that finds the first column that has an empty cell in the third row, but I cannot figure out how to return that integer.

```
Function FindEmptyColumn()
' Find the first empty column to paste data into

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Worksheets("Black Cam Raw Data").Activate
        Dim dCounter As Double
    dCounter = 1
    Dim iColumn As Integer
    Do Until Cells(3, dCounter) = ""
        iColumn = dCounter
        dCounter = dCounter + 1
    Loop
    iColumn = iColumn + 1
Return iColumn

End Function

Sub CMM_93Cam(ByVal wbTempName As Workbook)
'
' CMM_93Cam Macro
' This subroutine imports data from the CMM Report for a 195C93 Cam flatness measurement into this file.
'
    iColumn = FindEmptyColumn()
```

Basically, I get an error when I type the "Return iColumn" statement.  How do I get the function to return the value I have stored in iColumn?

Comment: To return value from function, you should use function name: write `FindEmptyColumn = iColumn` instead `Return iColumn`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Return` statement in VBA does not return the results of a function.  Use the function name instead.

Instead of:

```
Return iColumn
```

Use:

```
FindEmptyColumn = iColumn
```

---

In VBA, the `Return` statement is only used in conjunction with `GoSub`.

MSDN:  [GoSub...Return Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251648.aspx)